# Changing Django Timezone setting

Tags: python, django, postgresql, multi-tenant, saas

We have an "ERP like" project with `USE_TZ = False` in our settings and set TIME_ZONE to the desired zone requested by each client, since each client is different site (each client has it's own wsgi proccess and settings file)

But now we are moving to [django tenants](https://github.com/tomturner/django-tenants) (It gets the hostname in the middleware and changes DB schema according to it). And one settings file 
will rule them all.

Trying emulate previous behavior I wrote a middleware to change the timezone using `django.utils.timezone.activate` but if I call `datetime.datetime` I am always still getting the time using `settings.TIME_ZONE` instead the "activated" timezone.

How should I be dealing with timezone in this scenario?

Additional info:

- It is important that is always the same timezone for any user on the same subdomain(tenant) independently of the location of each user.
- We are using PostgreSQL timestamp with time zone fields.
- Al operations should remain with the date/time already have.

Comment: This topic could help https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/ .

Comment: Look at [django.utils.timezone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.timezone), e.g. `localtime()` and `now()`.